# Vue.js: Button disappears when adding v-on:click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using the example from https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers

I want to hide a message in `#content` when the button is clicked, but I encountered weird problem: `button` element disappears when `v-on:click` contains anything. When I remove "switch" from it, button appears on page.

Also, my second question: Is this the proper way of showing/hiding things using Vuejs?

My code:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <button v-on:click="switch">Switch</button>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <p v-if="show">{{ message}}</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script>
    var content = new Vue({
        el: '#content',
        data: {
            message: 'Hello Vue!',
            show: true
        }
    });

    var navigation = new Vue({
        el: '#navigation',
        data: {
        },
        methods: {
            switch: function() {
                content.show = !content.show;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`switch` is a reserved Javascript keyword, using another name such as `toggle` for the method will solve the problem.

```js
var content = new Vue({
  el: '#content',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!',
    show: true
  }
});

var navigation = new Vue({
  el: '#navigation',
  data: {},
  methods: {
    toggle: function() {
      content.show = !content.show;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="navigation">
  <button v-on:click="toggle">Switch</button>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <p v-if="show">{{ message}}</p>
</div>
```

As a side note, I strongly discourage the approach in this example. Vue instances should be isolated. Creating components is recommended and communication between them can happen via an event bus or vuex.